# HBRUSH to RGB value

Tags: winapi, gdi

Can you get the RGB value from `HBRUSH` or from brush id? for example: I'm looking for `GRAY_BRUSH` in RGB value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the [GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx) function to return a LOGBRUSH structure that contains the brush color.

Answer (score 1):

```
        static COLORREF lbColor;
        HBRUSH hb = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BACKGROUND);            
        LOGBRUSH br = { 0 };

        if (GetObject(hb, sizeof(br), &br))
        {
            lbColor = br.lbColor;

            RGBQUAD rgbq = { 0 };
            rgbq.rgbBlue = GetBValue(lbColor);
            rgbq.rgbGreen = GetGValue(lbColor);
            rgbq.rgbRed = GetRValue(lbColor);
            rgbq.rgbReserved = 0;
            //...
        }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.