# How to use stock-objects with GDI+

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I was using the following pattern to record an enhanced meta-file for a later playback:

```
POINT pts[] = {
//.....
};

::SelectObject(hEnhDC, ::GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
::Polygon(hEnhDC, pts, _countof(pts));
```

Now I'm forced to use GDI+ to provide anti-aliasing, so I'm trying to convert that code sample:

```
Gdiplus::Point pts[] = {
//...
};

Gdiplus::Graphics grx(hEnhDC);
Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, GetRValue(clrPen), GetGValue(clrPen), GetBValue(clrPen)), PEN_THICKNESS);

grx.FillPolygon(&brush, pts, _countof(pts));
grx.DrawPolygon(&pen, pts, _countof(pts));
```

The issue is how do I convert a stock-object `HBRUSH` from `::GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH)` to GDI+ `Brush` object?

---

**EDIT:** Guys, thank you for all your suggestions. And I apologize for not providing more details. This question is not about getting the `RGB` color triplet from the stock brush. I can do all that with the [GetSysColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor) function, or with the `LOGBRUSH` like you showed below.

The trick lies in the first sentence above. I am recording an enhanced metafile that may be played on a separate computer, so I cannot hard-code colors into it.

Let me explain. Say, the first GDI example (let's simplify it down to a triangle with a gray fill):

```
POINT pts[] = {
    {100, 100,},
    {100, 120,},
    {120, 100,},
};

::SelectObject(hEnhDC, ::GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
::Polygon(hEnhDC, pts, _countof(pts));
```

If I then call [GetEnhMetaFileBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getenhmetafilebits) on that meta-file, I'll get the following data:

[image]

So as you see the [`EMR_SELECTOBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-emf/145b063d-5f96-41fe-b7ae-1e615b2bc2bf) object in that recorded meta-file specifies the [`LTGRAY_BRUSH = 0x80000001`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-emf/d6dffd25-8615-42f8-aed1-309f1fe54ab2), which will be properly substituted for the color when that [meta-file is played](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-playenhmetafile) on the target system.

And that's what I'm trying to achieve here with GDI+. For some reason it only seems to support hard-coded color triplets in its [`Brush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusbrush/nl-gdiplusbrush-brush) class. That's why I asked.

Otherwise, one solution is to parse the enhanced meta-file's raw data. (For GDI+ it is a much more complex structure though, that also involves parsing `EMR_GDICOMMENT` objects.) And then substitute the needed color on the target system before the GDI+ meta-file is played. But it involves writing a lot of code, which I was trying to avoid at this stage ...

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use a stock object? Why not just pick a light grey color and make a brush from it?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Because `GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH)` may be a "light grey color" on your computer, but it may be a bright yellow one on someone else's who picks `high contrast` color scheme.

Comment: `LOGBRUSH lb;
     GetObjectW(GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH), sizeof(lb), &lb);
     Color clr;
     clr.SetFromCOLORREF(lb.lbColor);
     Pen pen(&SolidBrush(clr));`

Comment: @c00000fd Color scheme affects results of GetSysColor and GetSysColorBrush API calls. GetStockObject is different.

Comment: yeah, sorry everyone. I guess I didn't explain it with more details. Posted an update above.

Comment: I think you’re over-engineering things. Unlike windows borders and other theme-dependent stuff, stock brushes don’t change. MS has them documented over there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-emf/91c257d7-c39d-4a36-9b1f-63e3f73d30ca for decades now. The spec says `#C0C0C0`, and always did. It’s a data exchange format, after all.

Comment: @Soonts: maybe. I just want the software to comply with the users' accessibility settings.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid you can’t easily convert.

A simple workaround is [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusbrush/nf-gdiplusbrush-solidbrush-solidbrush(inconstcolor_)) GDI+ solid brush with the same color.

See [this spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-emf/d6dffd25-8615-42f8-aed1-309f1fe54ab2) for color values of GDI stock objects, that particular brush has color `#C0C0C0`

Comment: No it doesn't have color `#C0C0C0`. This is a user-defined parameter.

Comment: [Get the color from the stock brush first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612024/hbrush-to-rgb-value)?

Comment: @c00000fd Do you have a source for that, i.e. how to define the parameter?

Comment: @TheNextman it's not easy. Reading color in the spec is simpler.